# Sanctions against Russia and Internet subscriptions

Tags: internet, payment, sanctions, russia

Sanctions against Russia become heavier by the day, and an answer to that question might not fit the situation in a few weeks. Please consider the situation as of today.

Say a website located in the US works on a subscription-based business model.
The website offers some services, and anyone on the Internet can subscribe to the site and benefit from those services. The subscription being around $1~$5 / monthly.
The services are of an "entertainment" nature (gaming...).

Is it legal (from a US law PoV) to let a Russian national living in Moscow subscribe to the site, Internet-pay to an US bank, and benefit from the services? Would that collide with the sanctions? (provided that the payment service itself still works from Russia)

There is a related question, [*Is it legal to buy something online from Russia when they're currently under sanctions?*](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/78014/is-it-legal-to-buy-something-online-from-russia-when-theyre-currently-under-san), but mine is pretty much the opposite.